# DetailViewController can't set outlets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, master-detail

Hi i'm having an issue where DetailViewController doesn't want to set UILabel outlets, this is a Master Detail application template, when i press a cell here's what happens

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    // here it accordingly sets the ObjectItem to my custom object.

    Torrent *object = _torrents[indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setObjectItem:object];
   }
}
```

And here the method i call in DetailViewController viewDidLoad

```
- (void)configureView
{
// Since i set the objectItem earlier it works, it set the outlets
if (self.objectItem) {

    theTitle.text = self.objectItem.MovieTitleClean;
    genre.text = self.objectItem.Genre;
    size.text = self.objectItem.Size;
    quality.text = self.objectItem.Quality;
    rating.text = self.objectItem.MovieRating;
    year.text = self.objectItem.MovieYear;
}

if (self.detailObject) {

    ShortDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    self.details = [_detailObject objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Called"); // this is called meaning it should set the outlets but it doesn't...

resolution.text = self.details.Resolution;
framerate.text = self.details.FrameRate;
language.text = self.details.Language;
peersSeeds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",self.details.TorrentPeers,self.details.TorrentSeeds];
downloaded.text = self.details.Downloaded;
ShortDescription.text = self.details.ShortDescription;

}
```

In DetailViewController viewDidLoad i call configureView which sets the UILabel outlets to my custom objectItem and it works great, but when i receive new detailObject from a delegate and set the other UILabels according to that new detailObject nothing seems to be set at all (note) the view is already loaded and a NSlog shows that i call the configureView which means it suppose to set the outlets, i have to wait like 15 sec and it automatically set them all, does anyone have any idea why the view doesn't respond? it did in the first place. thanks

Edit: here's the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "TorrentDetail.h"

#import "YifyAPI.h"
#import "Torrent.h"

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <YifyAPIDelegate> {

IBOutlet UILabel *theTitle;
IBOutlet UILabel *genre;
IBOutlet UILabel *size;
IBOutlet UILabel *quality;
IBOutlet UILabel *rating;
IBOutlet UILabel *year;

IBOutlet UILabel *resolution;
IBOutlet UILabel *framerate;
IBOutlet UILabel *language;
IBOutlet UILabel *peersSeeds;
IBOutlet UILabel *downloaded;

IBOutlet UILabel *ShortDescription;

IBOutlet UIImageView *LargeImageCover;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) Torrent *objectItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) TorrentDetail *detailObject;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

this is normal because when you load the controller the object isn't set just then you load it for solve this problem you can do like that, in your detailControll, you implement the setter of your object like that:

```
-(void)setObjectItem:(Torrent *)object{

   if(_objectItem != object){
       _objectItem = object;
   }

    theTitle.text = self.objectItem.MovieTitleClean;
     genre.text = self.objectItem.Genre;
     size.text = self.objectItem.Size;
     quality.text = self.objectItem.Quality;
     rating.text = self.objectItem.MovieRating;
     year.text = self.objectItem.MovieYear;

}

-(void)setDetailObject:(NSArray *) detailObject{

   if(_detailObject != detailObject){
       _detailObject = detailObject;
   }

    ShortDescription.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    self.details = [_detailObject objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"Called"); // this is called meaning it should set the outlets but it doesn't...

     resolution.text = self.details.Resolution;
     framerate.text = self.details.FrameRate;
     language.text = self.details.Language;
     peersSeeds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",self.details.TorrentPeers,self.details.TorrentSeeds];
     downloaded.text = self.details.Downloaded;
     ShortDescription.text = self.details.ShortDescription;

    }
```

Comment: That is exactly what i did for both of them just call the [self configureView] at the end.

Comment: so if I solve your problem can you give me accept the answer, without give me a +1, that i want to take a special badge

Comment: the problem is still there, i meant both of the objects have the method you just wrote, but still the detailObject isn't shown in the view.

Comment: sure here it is - (void)didReceiveTorrentDetails:(NSArray*)torrentDetails
{
    NSLog(@"recieved torrent detials");
    if (_detailObject != torrentDetails) {
        _detailObject = torrentDetails;
        [self configureView];
    }
}

Comment: Still no success :/ i'm pretty sure it should work, but the view seems to freeze after NSLog(@"Called") called, then when i wait 15 sec it automatically sets them all.. so random

Comment: can you check with a nslog if self.details.Resolution exist?

Comment: i added NSLog(@"%@",resolution.text); at the end of the setDetailObject: it showed 1920*816 and i absolutely can't see anything on the view.

Comment: resolution is a label? is connected?

Comment: i added the .h file and yes they're all connected tried reconnecting still don't work

Comment: you have problem just with detailObject

Comment: it's the view that don't show the changes NSLog show there should be text in those UILabels but i can't see anything visually, i continue tomorrow, and maybe reinstall Xcode

Answer (score 0):

To configure properties in a view controller loaded from a storyboard, don't rely on viewDidLoad: to have the properties initialized. Both [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html) in the documentation say to override `awakeFromNib` to do configuration.

```
// In your Detail View Controller
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [self configureView];
    // Do any other configuration here
}
```

Comment: i can't request torrent details from awakeFomNib. and it's not the problem here, the view doesn't show any changes in outlets even though NSLog shows there should be text in UILabels but i can't see anything visually

Comment: If this was created in a storyboard, did you connect the outlets in Interface Builder? Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean.